# Cluster By Partitioning Syntax Error in Snowflake and Unable to load default data

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, syntax-error

I am new to snowflake. While I am trying to learn the snowflake I have encounter two problems i.e.

Problem #1

While I am trying to execute below command I am getting syntax error

Command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE PUBLIC.CUSTOMER_CLUSTER (
 C_CUSTKEY NUMBER(38,0),
 C_NAME VARCHAR(25),
 C_ADDRESS VARCHAR(40),
 C_NATIONKEY NUMBER(38,0),
 C_PHONE VARCHAR(15),
 C_ACCTBAL NUMBER(12,2),
 C_MKTSEGMENT VARCHAR(10),
 C_COMMENT VARCHAR(117),
 cluster BY (C_NATIONKEY)
);
```

Error:

> Syntax error line 11 at position 0 unexpected ')'

I am getting error at cluster by function.

Problem #2

```
insert into public.customer_nocluster 
    select * 
    from snowflake_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1000.CUSTOMER;
```

In the above command

```
customer_nocluster -> table_name
snowflake_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1000.CUSTOMER ->
```

where we are loading data from snowflake private data (default data available in account).

**Error:**

> String 'ly pending pinto beans. quickly pending requests use according to the furiously pending dolphins. carefully eve' is too long and would be truncated.

Can you please guide me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: For problem 1, you need to close your create table statement then cluster by (). `create table my_data (col1 int, col2 int) cluster by (col1);`

Comment: For problem 2, is there a limitation to the number of characters you are storing in that column? You may need to modify that column and expand the length. If table `public.customer_nocluster` has no information and you are starting from empty, then perhaps just use a CTAS statement for creating it.

Comment: Thank you for the information @Isolated. I have understand the Problem 1 but for problem 2 what I have to change in my syntax. Can you please little elaborate your answer with any syntax or example.

Comment: Generally it is not good practice to use SELECT * in this way. Explicitly list the columns in the target table, explicitly list the columns in the SELECT and make sure the two lists match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the second question:

if we find the row that is failing:

```
select * from snowflake_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1000.CUSTOMER
where c_comment like 'ly pending pinto beans. quickly pending requests%';
```

we get one row:

[image]

the length of that string is 111 bytes.

so if nocluster has a column width of 110

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE PUBLIC.CUSTOMER_NOCLUSTER (
 C_CUSTKEY NUMBER,
 C_NAME VARCHAR(25),
 C_ADDRESS VARCHAR(40),
 C_NATIONKEY NUMBER,
 C_PHONE VARCHAR(15),
 C_ACCTBAL NUMBER(12,2),
 C_MKTSEGMENT VARCHAR(10),
 C_COMMENT VARCHAR(110)
 );
```

and copy in, we get things like:

```
insert into public.customer_nocluster 
    select --*
        C_CUSTKEY
        ,C_NAME
        ,C_ADDRESS
        ,C_NATIONKEY
        ,C_PHONE
        ,C_ACCTBAL
        ,C_MKTSEGMENT
        ,C_COMMENT
    from snowflake_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1000.CUSTOMER;
```

> String 'the ironic deposits. blithely ironic packages for the quickly regular deposits engage slyly against the quickly s' is too long and would be truncated

so if we only take the first 110 characters:

```
insert into public.customer_nocluster 
    select --*
        C_CUSTKEY
        ,C_NAME
        ,C_ADDRESS
        ,C_NATIONKEY
        ,C_PHONE
        ,C_ACCTBAL
        ,C_MKTSEGMENT
        ,LEFT(C_COMMENT, 110)
    from snowflake_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1000.CUSTOMER;
```

it now runs happy:

[image]

So NickW point about the "don't use SELECT *" is that select star takes the columns in the order they where defined in the source table, or view, and if the definition of the table of view changes, the alignment can be broken, so it's a good habit to always be explicit in "production code". I use SELECT * when prototyping to "get it working" and once everything is as expected make the code boring/safe.

Comment: Thank you so much @Simeon Pilgrim for wonderful explanation where I have done wrong.